# eclipse maven nexus non-resolvable parent pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

Coming from the C#/Visual Studio world to the Java/Maven world, so be gentle with me. Plus, the guru who put all this together is not available to troubleshoot, so I've taken it on.

We have a project that when opened in Eclipse gives an immediate error on pom.xml:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for foo.bar.tool:r36.octy:2.1.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact
com.lab:abc-application-base:pom:3.5.2B from/to nexus-releases (https://nexus.tool.ads:8443
/nexus/content/repositories/releases/): Access denied to https://nexus.tool.ads:8443/nexus
/content/repositories/releases/com/lab/abc-application-base/3.5.2B/abc-application-base
-3.5.2B.pom. Error code 401, Unathorized and 'parent.relativePath' points at the wrong local POM
@ line 4, column 10
```

Here is the [parent] section from the local pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-application-base</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2B</version>
</parent>
```

Here is my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
    <localRepository>${USERPROFILE}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
    <proxies></proxies>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus-imported</id>
            <username>myusername</username>
            <password>{my-encrypted-password}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <username>myusername</username>
            <password>{my-encrypted-password}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors></mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <repositories>
                <id>nexus-releases</id>
                <name>releases</name>
                <url>https://nexus.tool.ads:8443/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            </repositories>
            <repositories>
                <id>nexus-imported</id>
                <name>imported</name>
                <url>https://nexus.tool.ads:8443/nexus/content/groups/oss/</url>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Based on my research here and elsewhere, I have added a [relativePath] tag to the pom.xml, empty, "..", and "../pom.xml" -- no luck. I have created and re-created both the encryption for the master password and my password. I have connected directly to the Nexus server, logging in with the same credentials in settings.xml and browsed to the POM in question. It is there. I have used the ?describe feature of Nexus to see what happens, and when authenticated by logging in, it returns a "FOUND" with all other indicators in the affirmative.

I'm wondering if Eclipse is failing to log me in to Nexus, but not really sure how to test that theory. Otherwise, I'm not one to throw darts until somethings sticks, but because this is a brave new world to me, I'm not sure what else to try or where else to look.

The silver bullet would be great, but just some constructive suggestions for troubleshooting would be good, too! Oh, it's Eclipse Mars.1 release 4.5.1, Maven 3.0.5, and Nexus 2.10.0-02. Oh, and fyi, this is all on a closed network without access to the Internet.

EDIT *** to answer Zeitounator's question:

Ok, the POM in question does not have a distributionManagement section. However, its parent POM actually points to another parent POM (which I guess would make the POM in question a grandchild)...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-maven-base</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2B</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

...and that grandparent POM *does* have this section:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>abc-maven-snapshot-repo</id>
        <name>ABC Maven Release Repo</name>
        <url>${repo.url}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>abc-maven-release-repo</id>
        <name>ABC Maven Snapshot Repo</name>
        <url>${repo.url}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

But clearly, I don't think it ever gets this far.

Comment: The 401 suggests invalid credentials.  Can you login to the nexus UI?

Comment: Really still using Maven 3.0.5 ?

Comment: Sorry, all!!! Internet access at work is sketchy at the moment, and I'm in class four nights a week... Andrew, yes, per above "I have connected directly to the Nexus server, logging in with the same credentials in settings.xml and browsed to the POM in question." khmarbaise, I'm new to both Maven and the environment in this office. I'm trying to learn the first and have no control over the second.

Comment: Can you show the DistributionManagement part of your pom.xml if you have one.

Comment: That doesn't seem familiar. I'll check when I get to the office here in a bit, but may not be able to respond until later this afternoon... thanks!

Comment: Answering your question by editing the post...